# Keyboard with NSNotificationCenter in swift

Tags: swift, keyboard, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to convert obj-c code to swift for moving content that is located under the keyboard. I am having a issue named "CGPoint is not convertible to CGRect" in keyboardWillShown() method. I don't know how to handle this. Below is my code portion -

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications (){
    var center1 = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center1.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShown"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

    var center2 = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center2.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillBeHidden"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func registerForKeyboardNotifications (){
    var center1 = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center1.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShown"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

    var center2 = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center2.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillBeHidden"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset  = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
        if !CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.textView.frame.origin) {
            //This below line shows error
            self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(self.textView.frame.origin, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden() {
    println("Keyboard hidden")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED!

Keyboard and Text View, this is perhaps near to what we are looking for, try that out.

In this code I don't use `scrollView` and instead of moving the `textView.frame`, I use `contentInset` to keep track of the cursor.

In your viewDidLoad registerForKeyboardNotification and set your delegate to self:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    registerForKeyboardNotification()
    textView.delegate = self
}
```

Then you do like:

```
func registerForKeyboardNotification() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWasShown:"), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillBeHidden:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let info = aNotification.userInfo!
    let kbSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey])!.CGRectValue.size
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0)
    textView.contentInset = contentInsets
    textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    textView.contentInset = contentInsets
    textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

That worked for me with Xcode 7 beta 4. Hope that helps someone.